# How to add a new column to the gridview in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have 4 columns in my `GridView`, which contains the data I need, but now I need one more column. How can I create it in my `GridView`?

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'employment_date',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
      ],
    ]); ?>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about add column `this_is_my_important_column` to table in database and then add `'this_is_my_important_column'` to `columns` in `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add more columns according to yii  api:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
    [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'employment_date',

        [
            'class' => DataColumn::className(), // this line is optional
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Name',
        ],
        ['class' => CheckboxColumn::className()],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ]
]); ?>
```

you can read [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$columns-detail)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ....
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'employment_date',
        'columns'=>[
             'attribute'=>'New Column',
             'value'=>'tbl.new_column'    
        ],
        //OR This
        new_column,
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
      ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: I think your answer would be even better if you could fix the formatting so that it uses a code block.